# Qt C++ Load GUI then load other settings

Tags: c++, qt

I'm making large application which needs to be fast. I have one window which is loaded, then I scale 6 images to around 126x105 size and then set them as icons on 6 PushButtons. This process takes around 2 seconds to complete and GUI is not displayed until those 6 pictures are scaled. Is there any method to show GUI and after GUI is loaded then scale images and set them as icons. 
This is the code:

```
    f = new QFrame(this);
    f->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 85%);"
                     "border: 2px solid green;"
                     "border-radius: 12px;");
    f->setGeometry(this->width/2-250, this->height/2-200, 500, 300);
    f->show();

    frameZatvori = new QPushButton(this);
    frameZatvori->setFlat(true);
    frameZatvori->setFont(QFont("Droid Sans", 9, QFont::Bold));
    frameZatvori->setGeometry(f->x()+475, f->y()+10, 15, 15);
    frameZatvori->setText("X");
    frameZatvori->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
    frameZatvori->show();

    promjenaP1 = new QPushButton(this);
    promjenaP1->setFlat(true);
    promjenaP1->setStyleSheet("border-color: solid blue;"
                              "border: 3px;"
                              "border-radius: 9px;");

    promjenaP1->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
    promjenaP1->setGeometry(f->x()+30, f->y()+30, 126, 105);
    promjenaP1->show();

    promjenaP2 = new QPushButton(this);
    promjenaP2->setFlat(true);
    promjenaP2->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
    promjenaP2->setGeometry(promjenaP1->x()+156, f->y()+30, 126, 105);
    promjenaP2->show();

    promjenaP3 = new QPushButton(this);
    promjenaP3->setFlat(true);
    promjenaP3->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
    promjenaP3->setGeometry(promjenaP2->x()+156, f->y()+30, 126, 105);
    promjenaP3->show();

    promjenaP4 = new QPushButton(this);
    promjenaP4->setFlat(true);
    promjenaP4->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
    promjenaP4->setGeometry(f->x()+30, promjenaP1->y()+135, 126, 105);
    promjenaP4->show();

    promjenaP5 = new QPushButton(this);
    promjenaP5->setFlat(true);
    promjenaP5->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
    promjenaP5->setGeometry(promjenaP1->x()+156, promjenaP1->y()+135, 126, 105);
    promjenaP5->show();

    promjenaP6 = new QPushButton(this);
    promjenaP6->setFlat(true);
    promjenaP6->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
    promjenaP6->setGeometry(promjenaP2->x()+156, promjenaP1->y()+135, 126, 105);
    promjenaP6->show();

    QObject::connect(frameZatvori, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(zatvoriPozadineFunkcija()));

    QPixmap slika("/home/alen/QtSDK/writer/Pozadine/slika.jpg");
    QPixmap prebaci = slika.scaled(126, 105, Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::FastTransformation);
    promjenaP1->setIcon(prebaci);
    promjenaP1->setIconSize(QSize(126, 105));
    QPixmap slika1("/home/alen/QtSDK/writer/Pozadine/slika1.jpg");
    QPixmap prebaci1 = slika1.scaled(126, 105, Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::FastTransformation);
    promjenaP2->setIcon(prebaci1);
    promjenaP2->setIconSize(QSize(126, 105));
    QPixmap slika2("/home/alen/QtSDK/writer/Pozadine/slika2.jpg");
    QPixmap prebaci2 = slika2.scaled(126, 105, Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::FastTransformation);
    promjenaP3->setIcon(prebaci2);
    promjenaP3->setIconSize(QSize(126, 105));
    QPixmap slika3("/home/alen/QtSDK/writer/Pozadine/slika3.jpg");
    QPixmap prebaci3 = slika3.scaled(126, 105, Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::FastTransformation);
    promjenaP4->setIcon(prebaci3);
    promjenaP4->setIconSize(QSize(126, 105));
    QPixmap slika4("/home/alen/QtSDK/writer/Pozadine/slika4.jpg");
    QPixmap prebaci4 = slika4.scaled(126, 105, Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::FastTransformation);
    promjenaP5->setIcon(prebaci4);
    promjenaP5->setIconSize(QSize(126, 105));
    QPixmap slika5("/home/alen/QtSDK/writer/Pozadine/slika5.jpg");
    QPixmap prebaci5 = slika5.scaled(126, 105, Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::FastTransformation);
    promjenaP6->setIcon(prebaci5);
    promjenaP6->setIconSize(QSize(126, 105));
```

Comment: Loads of ways, although the best way would be to have them pre-scaled.

Comment: Why not pre-scale the images and store them in a `.qrc` file?

Comment: You can use a thread (best idea if you don't want to block the UI) or use a queued signal/slot connection that to send from the constructor that will fire once the event loop starts going.

Comment: if you use a thread you will not be able to use QPixmap - you'd have to use QImage and then convert to QPixmap in the main thread

Comment: I can only guess which original size you have and on which machine it's running, that scaling takes that long.

Comment: @trojanfoe I can't pre-scale images because later on I need to implement function which allows user to input his own images. This is only test, just to see how it's going.

Comment: Those images are some kind of thumbnails, they are preview of real images, which are usually big.

Answer (score 0):

Your GUI is not displayed because application events are not processed at this time (I suppose you're doing all this in the main thread). Try to postpone scaling pixmaps, for example, use `QTimer::singleShot()` and do this in timer callback.

Comment: That was mine idea too but how can I know which time interval to put, some computer are slower and other are faster then mine so that time interval will be variable.

Comment: @Alen, you can use interval 0, in this case `QTimer` will fire as soon as all the events in the window system's event queue have been processed. See [QTimer::interval](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html#interval-prop). Of course, timer callback will block your UI again, but at least your UI will show sooner. Also, you may want to spawn separate thread for thumbnail generation, as @Pete suggested.